# .NET CLI how to run app after publish on Linux

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I spent ~4 hours investigation and still can't find out how to run published application ( `dotnet publish` )

Now I can download sources to my remote machine, then call `dotnet build` and `dotnet run` - then my app runs as intended. But I want to publish just DLL's (or *.so ?) to my VPS without source files.

**What official docs says?** To define command in project.json

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://unix:/var/aspnet/HelloMVC/kestrel.sock",
}
```

But it is obsolette, isn't it?

**What about default samples?**

In default VS2015 sample solution they use publish-iis, Full .NET framework and IIS server, but there is nothing about deployment on linux.

```
postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
```

---

Here is my dotnet info

```
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview1-002702)

Product Information:
 Version:     1.0.0-preview1-002702
 Commit Sha:  6cde21225e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.10586
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
```

.NET Core RC2

Comment: You need to add the RID to the project.json under a node called runtimes. And the publish for it (do not forget to remove the "type":"platform" thingy from your dependencies. http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/app-types.html

Comment: dotnet publish -r ubuntu.14.04-x64 works for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do the following steps (starting from a RC2 portable application; the normal one):

1. Remove the "type": "platform" annotation from all your dependencies (so it is actuall self-contained and no longer rely on a installed .NET Core platform).
2. Add a node runtimes to your project.json (so NuGet is able to pull the necessary platform parts to your local machine)

   Sample:

   ```
   "runtimes": {
     "osx.10.11-x64": { },
     "win10-x64": { },
     "ubuntu.14.04-x64": { }
   }
   ```
3. `dotnet restore` (to make sure the new runtimes are locally available).
4. `dotnet build` (if not already done for the portable app)
5. `dotnet publish -r ubuntu.14.04-x64` (to bundle it up)
6. See the result directory with a platform specific dotnet command able to run the app.

I followed the steps found in the [.NET Core documentation](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/app-types.html).

Comment: Okay, now I have all these files under "publish" folder. I uploaded these files to my ubuntu server and called dotnet run command, but still no resut - I'm getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you called it locally? or your shared framework installation? Not that it should make a difference.

Comment: my question was more: have you called it locally like `./dotnet run Foobar.dll` or `dotnet run Foobar.dll` (the dot is the difference ;))

Comment: Thank you man, I did not set Foobar.dll as a param, that was the problem. Now it works. Can you please tell me why it is important to set a name of DLL, because "dotnet run" works just fine on my local dev. environment

Comment: I think the difference is the project.json, which is locally just the element to execute, while compiled you need to be more explicit. I am a bit surprised by publish that it does not come with a shell script like before. But hey, it is preview1.

Comment: It does produce output similar to dnx, but only when the app is self-contained.  If you're not seeing that in your publish output then you might still need to make some changes to your project.json to make the app self-contained instead of portable.

Comment: In NET .Core Final, to run "published" DLL you need to run it with `dotnet mydll.dll` without `run` keyword, see info in official docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-run

Comment: @DanielGrim I'm trying to do the same except to OSX.

Do you know the steps or where I can find it & do I need 'ubuntu.14.04-x64' installed through nuget?

On my mac, after creating a directory to save my application I just created/copied from Windows - do I need to install yoeman or anything else?

Lastly, will i execute it by typing 'dotnet run' on my mac?

I'm on day two trying to figure this out.

Comment: Link to .NET Core documentation is broken.

Comment: yes , anyone can re new the links ? page not found