# Asp.net core publish no longer creates shell scripts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I had a similar problem to the questions asked here [asp.net core publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376880/net-cli-how-to-run-app-after-publish-on-linux) and i have followed the answers and got my asp.net core web app to publish but it seems unlike earlier version it no longer creates the shell and cmd scripts like it did before when --no-source was used with dotnet publish. Is there anyway to get this back?

Answer (score 1):

No, they're gone. Hopefully you don't need them anymore, you should be able to start the project via dotnet.exe or mac/linux equivalent.